# Trouble With Inner Join MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL Inner Join query and HTML table.

Table 1: daily_info
Table 2: stocks

The join is performed on a column called "Symbol" which is present in both tables. Unfortunately, no data is being generated in the HTML table below. What am I missing?

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT daily_info.Day, daily_info.Prev_close, stocks.Symbol, stocks.Company, stocks.Description FROM stocks INNER JOIN daily_info ON stocks.Symbol = daily_info.Symbol ORDER BY Day Desc"; 

$result = mysqli_query( $link, $query );


// All good?
if ( !$result ) {
  // Nope
  $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
  die( $message );
}

?>
<br />
<hr />
<br />
<div id="table-wrapper">
<div id="table-scroll">
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'">
<thead><tr>
  <th><span class="text">Company</span></th>
  <th><span class="text">Symbol</span></th>
  <th><span class="text">Previous Close</span></th>
</tr></thead>
<?php
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" . $row['Symbol'] . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $row['Company'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" . $row['Symbol'] . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $row['Symbol'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Prev_close'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_error()` which does not mix with `mysqli_*` functions. Change it to `mysqli_error($link)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping on the `$query` string -> `$query = "SELECT daily_info.Day,...`

```
<?php
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
                                  ^^^^^^
```

Where you need to loop on the `$result` resource -> `$result = mysqli_query( $link, $query );`

```
<?php
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                                  ^^^^^^^
```